# VisualPlugin reading contact forces crashes gazebo (black screen)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm making my own gazebo plugin to read the contact forces on an object and the change the visual information accordingly. So far, I've been combining:

- A tutorial on a gazebo subscriber (http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=topics_subscribed&cat=transport)
- A thread on creating a VisualPlugin for Gazebo (http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1377/visuals-material-update-from-modelplugin-in-ros/)

The plugin I made compiles fine but gives me a black screen when gazebo starts and crashes after about 100 iterations (becomes unresponsive). Verbose mode gives me no errors except a warning after about 30 seconds: "[Wrn] [Publisher.cc:131] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/pose/local/info, deleting message. This warning is printed only once."

Are there any other ways to figure out exactly why my plugin is crashing? I think it might have something to do with the way I create the subscriber. Here's my code:

[material_plugin.h](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14332375698510906.h)

[material_plugin3.cpp](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14332375868233586.cpp)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8844/visualplugin-reading-contact-forces-crashes-gazebo-(black-screen)/) by [niall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1200/niall/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 96 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here's what worked in the end:

[material_plugin3.cpp](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14332781754402164.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [niall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1200/niall/) with karma: 96 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You have an infinite `while` loop in your `OnUpdate()` function which will block Gazebo. Any Event connection from Gazebo, must return. It's also a good idea to return as quickly as possible.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1200/niall/) on 2015-06-02**:
You are totally right, thanks. Though I don't fully understand how this does work in the standalone subscriber (with a main) and not in this plugin... Anyway, removing it, along with some other changes, did the trick. I'll post the code below for others as reference :).

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-06-02**:
A plugin is managed by Gazebo, which has it's own main loop. In a standalone program you have to write your own main loop.